# grails: how to set the targetUrlParameter for SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler/AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler

Tags: grails

I want to redirect dynamically after a successfull login depending on some conditions. So I added
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.targetUrlParameter = 'myTargetUrlParam'
to my config.groovy but now i wonder where and more how to set the "targetUrlParameter" so the "AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler" can access it. "request.getParameter(targetUrlParameter)" (in line 10 below) returns null.

```
protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl()) {
        return defaultTargetUrl;
    }

    // Check for the parameter and use that if available
    String targetUrl = null;

    if (targetUrlParameter != null  ) {
        targetUrl = request.getParameter(targetUrlParameter);

        if (StringUtils.hasText(targetUrl)) {
            logger.debug("Found targetUrlParameter in request: " + targetUrl);

            return targetUrl;
        }
    }

    if (useReferer && !StringUtils.hasLength(targetUrl)) {
        targetUrl = request.getHeader("Referer");
        logger.debug("Using Referer header: " + targetUrl);
    }

    if (!StringUtils.hasText(targetUrl)) {
        targetUrl = defaultTargetUrl;
        logger.debug("Using default Url: " + targetUrl);
    }

    return targetUrl;
}
```

I tried

```
params.myTargetUrlParam = 'some url to redirect to'
```

in my LoginController but that didn't work out. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the target url parameter to the url you use to submit your login form.

For example your LoginController might return a view containing a login form:

```
<g:form url="/j_spring_security_check?myTargetUrlParam=your-redirect-url">
  <!-- fields for username and password -->
</g:form>
```

Comment: No that didn't work and I thought "url" would be the wrong attribute? I also tried 'params="[mySuperSecretParam:your-redirect-url]"' but that didn't work either